# How to use CTAGS and VIM in a case_insensitive way?

Tags: vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I am using ctags in conjunction with VIM, which is a quite powerful combination to speed up coding. In order to enable autocompletion for a set of IDL routines I've generated the CTAGS file with the contents the IDL source code I want to use. So far so good.

The problem I am facing now is that when I start typing in VIM the name of one of the IDL library functions in a different case than the one used to define the library, VIM would not be able to find it. The question then is, is there any way in which I can fold the case in the autocompletion using VIM and CTAGS?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `help tag-regexp`. It will use the value of the `'ignorecase'` setting.